# PDF rendering Issue when Break Tag Is Used

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rendered

I am getting this Issues in Vf Page when rendered as PDF

"To" is Taking  Spaces

This is my HTML Tag

```
<b>To,</b><br/>
<b>ABC XYZ Ltd</b>
```

[image]

when I Use the `<br/>` Tag I Am Facing this Issues

Comment: You could try rendering the page as HTML so that you can inspect the element to see what is being outputted.

Comment: @BarCotter In HTML Page it is coming Properly

Comment: Adding more of your code will help other figure out the problem. Especially if you have any custom styling in place. The code snippet you provided does not replicate the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I think I found the issue there was a Div with alingn="justify"

some code

Once I removed the "justify" it is working properly

Answer (score 1):

If i create the following page, i cannot see any problem:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <b>To,</b><br/>
    <b>ABC XYZ Ltd</b>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

There seems to be some strange acting CSS on your side.

You could render the page as HTML and inspect the styles, which are getting applied.